Having to query a model before populating it otherwise it throws this error: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Grade"
I am trying to fetch tutors:
await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI);

const subjects = await Subject.find();

const grades = await Grade.find();

const tutors = await Tutor.find()
    .populate('gradeSubjects.grade')
    .populate('gradeSubjects.subject')

If I don't add the lines that fetch subjects and grades I get this error:
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Grade".
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Subject".

I don't understand why this happens.
Here are the definitions of the models:

Tutor

import mongoose, { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

const tutorSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    gradeSubjects: [
        {
            grade: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Grade', required: true },
            subject: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subject', required: true }
        }
    ]
});

const Tutor = models.Tutor || model('Tutor', tutorSchema);

export default Tutor;


Grade

import mongoose, { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

const gradeSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    subjects: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subject' }],  // Reference to subjects
});

const Grade = models.Grade || model('Grade', gradeSchema);

export default Grade;


Subject

import mongoose, { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

const subjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
});

const Subject = models.Subject || model('Subject', subjectSchema);

export default Subject;

Any idea what's going on?

Have you tried just importing the Subject and Grade model into the file where you execute the Tutor.find() query. You shouldn't need to run a query for Subject and Grade. So long as the models are registered on the mongoose.models. You can manually pass the models to the populate method but that's for specific use cases and overkill for what you are doing.

Yes. They're actually imported there. Otherise I wouldn't be able to execute Tutor.find()

No models don't have to be imported. They can be passed as function arguments or in a class constructor for example. It's unclear from your snippet where the Subject & Grade models are coming from or if they're even registered on the same connection. You could be using Multiple connections. More code would help to see where things are going wrong. As a quick fix just pass the model like so: Tutor.find().populate({ path: 'gradeSubjects.grade', model: Grade }).populate({ path: 'gradeSubjects.subject', model: Subject }).
